# Preview links generated for .csv and .xls files erroring out

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

When testing the [**preview**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint for .xls and .csv files a *getUrl* is returned as if the operation has been successful,
But when using the returned link the preview page just seems to error out, as per below:

[image]

Is there a way to generate embedable .csv and .xls previews through Microsoft Graph?